# A user has multiple sessions ,overlapping and individual sessions, find out tot time for each user overlapping and non overlapping sessions

Tags: sql-server, gaps-and-islands

```
username year  month  day     timein                    time out 
xyz      2012  12     05    2012-12-05 08:10:34.500      2012-12-05 11:23:45:508
xyz      2012  12     05    2012-12-05 09:11:14.352      2012-12-05 11:00:45:378
xyz      2012  12     05    2012-12-05 09:50:34.547      2012-12-05 12:23:45:508
xyz      2012  12     05    2012-12-05 12:06:11.119      2012-12-05 01:23:01:290
xyz      2012  12     05    2012-12-05 02:10:34.547      2012-12-05 04:23:45:508
```

The first 4 rows show overlapping sessions and last row is non-overlapping session.
I need a query to calculate total time for this user and also to display all sessions with the calculated time.

Comment: What do you expect as output from your sample data?

Comment: It might be more productive to combine the overlapping sessions, then trivially print them out.

Comment: the output should be 9.012200 for all the rows

Comment: select  DATEDIFF(SECOND,@Date01 ,@Date02 )*1.00  / (60*60) I used this query to calculate the total time

Comment: This should be displayed on a ssrs report, so I want to display all sessions and show the calculated time as total time as a row for each user, just like working using a matrix

Answer (score 0):

for the example data.

```
CREATE TABLE Session
    ([username] varchar(3), [year] int, [month] int, [day] int, [timein] datetime, [timeout] datetime, CHECK([timeout] >= [timein]) )
;

INSERT INTO Session
    ([username], [year], [month], [day], [timein], [timeout])
VALUES
    ('xyz', 2012, 12, 05, '2012-12-05 08:10:34', '2012-12-05 11:23:45'),
    ('xyz', 2012, 12, 05, '2012-12-05 09:11:14', '2012-12-05 11:00:45'),
    ('xyz', 2012, 12, 05, '2012-12-05 09:50:34', '2012-12-05 12:23:45'),
    ('xyz', 2012, 12, 05, '2012-12-05 12:06:11', '2012-12-05 13:23:01'),
    ('xyz', 2012, 12, 05, '2012-12-05 02:10:34', '2012-12-05 04:23:45')
;
```

When the rows for a user are ordered by `timein` we know that if the `timein` of the current row is less than or equal to a previously seen `timeout` value that this row does not start a new session. Otherwise it does start a new session.

```
WITH T1
     AS (SELECT *,
                MAX(timeout) OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY timein) AS max_time_out_so_far
         FROM   Session),
     T2
     AS (SELECT *,
                LAG(max_time_out_so_far) OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY timein) AS prev_max_time_out_so_far
         FROM   T1),
     T3
     AS (SELECT *,
                SUM(session_start) OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY timein) AS session_group
         FROM   T2
                CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN timein <= prev_max_time_out_so_far THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) CA(session_start))
SELECT *
FROM   T3 
ORDER BY timein
```

The results of the above for the sample data are

```
+----------+------+-------+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+---------------+---------------+
| username | year | month | day |         timein          |         timeout         |   max_time_out_so_far   | prev_max_time_out_so_far | session_start | session_group |
+----------+------+-------+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+---------------+---------------+
| xyz      | 2012 |    12 |   5 | 2012-12-05 02:10:34.000 | 2012-12-05 04:23:45.000 | 2012-12-05 04:23:45.000 | NULL                     |             1 |             1 |
| xyz      | 2012 |    12 |   5 | 2012-12-05 08:10:34.000 | 2012-12-05 11:23:45.000 | 2012-12-05 11:23:45.000 | 2012-12-05 04:23:45.000  |             1 |             2 |
| xyz      | 2012 |    12 |   5 | 2012-12-05 09:11:14.000 | 2012-12-05 11:00:45.000 | 2012-12-05 11:23:45.000 | 2012-12-05 11:23:45.000  |             0 |             2 |
| xyz      | 2012 |    12 |   5 | 2012-12-05 09:50:34.000 | 2012-12-05 12:23:45.000 | 2012-12-05 12:23:45.000 | 2012-12-05 11:23:45.000  |             0 |             2 |
| xyz      | 2012 |    12 |   5 | 2012-12-05 12:06:11.000 | 2012-12-05 13:23:01.000 | 2012-12-05 13:23:01.000 | 2012-12-05 12:23:45.000  |             0 |             2 |
+----------+------+-------+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

The `session_group` is just a running total of the number of `session_start` flags encountered so far.

This can be used in a grouping query as in the full example below.

```
WITH T1
     AS (SELECT *,
                MAX(timeout) OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY timein) AS max_time_out_so_far
         FROM   Session),
     T2
     AS (SELECT *,
                CASE
                  WHEN timein <= LAG(max_time_out_so_far) OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY timein)
                    THEN 0
                  ELSE 1
                END AS session_start
         FROM   T1),
     T3
     AS (SELECT *,
                SUM(session_start) OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY timein) AS session_group
         FROM   T2),
     T4
     AS (SELECT username,
                session_group,
                MIN(timein)                                 AS timein,
                MAX(timeout)                                AS timeout,
                DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(timein), MAX(timeout)) AS session_duration
         FROM   T3
         GROUP  BY username,
                   session_group)
SELECT CASE WHEN GROUPING(username) = 0 THEN username ELSE 'TOTAL' END AS username,
       session_group,
       timein,
       timeout,
       SUM(session_duration) AS session_duration
FROM   T4
GROUP  BY GROUPING SETS ( ( username, session_group, timein, timeout ), ( ) )
```

which returns

```
+----------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+
| username | session_group |         timein          |         timeout         | session_duration |
+----------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+
| xyz      | 1             | 2012-12-05 02:10:34.000 | 2012-12-05 04:23:45.000 |             7991 |
| xyz      | 2             | 2012-12-05 08:10:34.000 | 2012-12-05 13:23:01.000 |            18747 |
| TOTAL    | NULL          | NULL                    | NULL                    |            26738 |
+----------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you Martin Smith, It is working fine for my scenario...:)

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 and unable to use LAG function as it is starting from 2012 server. Can you suggest any other alternative to achieve the same functionality